# How to determine how long a user is using the app (swift4)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out how to determine the time the user has been on the app so then I can create an "analytics" view in the app. This is what I have tried so far:

In my AppDelegate.swift file I made the following global variables:

```
var time1: Double = 0.0
var time2: Double = 0.0
var time3: Double = 0.0
var totalTime : Double = 0.0
```

In the `func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)`

I wrote the following:

```
let date = Date()
        let interval = date.timeIntervalSince1970
        time2 = interval
        totalTime = totalTime - time2
        print("The time the application exited is \(time2)")
        time3 = time2 - time1
        print("The time of the session is \(time3)")

        totalTime = totalTime + time3

        print("The total time that the user is using the app is \(totalTime)")
```

Lastly, in the `func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)`

I wrote the following:

```
let date = Date()
        let interval = date.timeIntervalSince1970
        time1 = interval

        print("The time the application started is \(time1)")
```

So this works...ish but the issue is that when I launch the app I get the following output:

`The time the application exited is 1544032302.303546
The time of the session is 1544032302.303546
The total time that the user is using the app is 1544032302.303546`

This is because it's referencing 1970. I am not sure how to get past this and make it just start counting when the user launches the app. **There are similar questions out there but not very clear into how to get the following time usage of the app.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a few points you're missing here. The first and most obvious to me is that if you store these data as variables in the delegate, they will not persist between launches which will undermine your goal if I understand it correctly. You should check out a persistent data store. UserDefaults is generally the easiest to use but you should do some research to see if it's right for your use case.

Also, there's no reason you *need* to work with time intervals that count from epoch.

In general I am also not a fan of maintaining the state of all of these Doubles when I think it's saner and safer to just compare dates and let Foundation help you out with the math.

This is a very basic example of the implementation of these suggestions:

```
   var appBecameActiveDate: Date!
   static let uptimeKey = "uptime"

   func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
      appBecameActiveDate = Date()
   }

   func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(totalUptime, forKey: AppDelegate.uptimeKey)
   }

   var totalUptime: Double {
      let previousUptime = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: AppDelegate.uptimeKey)
      let sessionTime = appBecameActiveDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
      return previousUptime - sessionTime
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes it much simpler than what I had it before. I just have two questions. If I want to call the totalUpTime variable in another view, how can I go about that, I tried making all the variables global but that doesn't work. My other question, how can I make it know if a new day has started? this way I can store the totalUpTime some where and then reset it for the next day. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Actually I was able to figure that out, simply by using the following reference: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate and then extending it to grab the variable. Still not sure about the second question.